# C++ Builder: interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c++, delphi, com, c++builder, vcl

In order to use a COM object from a thread, I inserted CoInitialize(NULL) into the thread Execute function and CoUninitialize() into the Terminate function.

Everything works fine, except if the user aborts the thread by calling the Terminate function from the calling form.

It seems that the Terminate function called by a form is considered as another thread (Error message: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread').

On the other hand I cannot put the code into a specific function to call by using Synchronize. This way makes the program still until the COM process of called function ends.

I know that functions to readdress the COM marshaling exist. But don't know exactly what to do. I did not find examples in C++, too.

Before asking help, I tried various ways to overcome the problem. Unfortunately I am here.

Here is my code:

```
class TThreadCamera : public TThread
{
private:
  Variant Camera;

protected:
  void __fastcall Execute();

public:
  void __fastcall Terminate(TObject *Sender);

public:
  __fastcall TThreadCamera();

};
```

-

```
__fastcall TThreadCamera::TThreadCamera()
  : TThread(false)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TThreadCamera::Execute()
{
  FreeOnTerminate = true;
  OnTerminate = &Terminate;
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  Camera = Variant::CreateObject("ASCOM.Simulator.Camera");
  Camera.OlePropertySet("Connected", true);
  Camera.OleProcedure("StartExposure", 60, true);
  while ((! (bool) Camera.OlePropertyGet("ImageReady")))
    Sleep 100;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TThreadCamera::Terminate(TObject *Sender)
{
  if (Camera.OlePropertyGet("CameraState") == 2) // Exposure currently in progress
    Camera.OleProcedure("AbortExposure");
  CoUninitialize();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize` on the same thread, since they act on the calling thread. The `OnTerminate` event is always executed on the main thread.

So, remove your `OnTerminate` event handler, move that code into the thread, and so call `CoUninitialize` from the thread:

```
void __fastcall TThreadCamera::Execute()
{
  FreeOnTerminate = true;
  CoInitialize(NULL);

  Camera = Variant::CreateObject("ASCOM.Simulator.Camera");
  // code to operate on the camera goes here

  CoUninitialize();
}
```

It would probably be prudent to protect the uninitialization inside a finally block.

Comment: Thanks, 
Unfortunately this way does not help, since if the user calls Terminate while the StartExposure is in progress (60 seconds long), the Couninitialize() was not yet executed.

Comment: This is what you need to do. All the code needs to be executed in the thread. From COM initialization right through to finalization. Regarding calls to `Terminate`, your code doesn't test `Terminated` and since the thread is a free on terminate thread, you aren't allowed to hold a reference to it anyway.

Comment: So you need to decide what to do about free on terminate. If you want to retain a reference to the thread, you can't use free on terminate or at least you need to clear the reference in the OnTerminate handler. And if you want to be able to use Terminate you need to check the Terminated property. So there are likely many problems with your code. But the answer to the question about the COM uninit is as I stated.

Comment: The 'code to operate on the camera' you mentioned takes a long duration (from a few seconds to 10 or more of minutes in astro-photography).
If the user decides to stop the process by calling Terminate, while the CoUninitialize has not processed, the problem remains the same: ''The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread''.
Any other solution?

Comment: You are not listening. There is no alternative to calling CoUninitialize on the thread that called CoInitialize. Eventually you'll accept that. However, Terminate does not work on your thread for the reasons I explained.

Comment: `TThread.Terminate()` simply sets the `TThread.Terminated` property to true, it does nothing else. It is the responsibility of your `Execute()` method to check `Terminated` periodically and act accordingly. The thread (main thread?) that calls `Terminate()` can call `TThread.WaitFor()` to wait for the camera thread to actually terminate. You cannot use `TThread.WaitFor` with `FreeOnTerminate=True`, though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You did not say anything about `WaitFor()`, or how `Terminate()` works. So I did.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi, if you need to call a thread termination code in the thread context, you should override the protected `TThread.DoTerminate` method instead of writing `OnTerminate` event handler.

Comment: That's true but it would be odd to separate init and finit in that way

Comment: Maybe; but it seems like overriding `DoTerminate` is the straightforward fix to the OP code..

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. Would you?

Comment: It depends on my current mood and the phase of moon. :)

Comment: What may be important is that `DoTerminate` will be called always, even if `Execute` is not called. So yes, it is better to put `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize` calls to `Execute`.

Comment: `DoTerminate()` is also called if `Execute()` throws an uncaught exception. A `try/__finally` would work, but it also involves some overhead to use. So it is a matter of personal choice one way or the other.

Comment: Even if that were not an issue I can't imagine any scenario where I would want to separate init from finit in that way. I guess we have different opinions here.

Comment: @Remy DoTerminate runs if Execute does not

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, but only if `Terminate()` is called before the thread calls `Execute()`. In any case, this is a simple example. In more complex examples, threads typically have more cleanup to perform. Sometimes overriding `DoTerminate()` makes sense, when RAII is not used, and nested `try/_finally` is ugly or impractical.

Comment: @Remy I don't see the downsides with finally or RAII. I see downsides from splitting init from finit in such a far from idiomatic manner. If the finit code is too long, extract it into a method.

Answer (score 1):

The `TThread.OnTerminate` event is called in the context of the main UI thread. The  virtual `TThread.DoSynchronize()` method, which the worker thread calls after `Execute()` exits, uses `TThread.Synchronize()` to call `OnTerminate`.  `DoTerminate()` is always called, even if `Execute()` exits due to an uncaught exception, so overriding `DoTerminate()` is a good way to perform thread-specific cleanup.

`CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize()` must be called in the same thread.  So, you must call `CoUninitialize()` inside of `Execute()`, or override `DoTerminate()`. I prefer the latter, as it reduces the need for using `try/catch` or `try/__finally` blocks in `Execute()` (an RAII solution, such as `TInitOle` in `utilscls.h`, is even better).

An apartment-threaded COM object can only be accessed in the context of the thread that creates it.  So you must call the camera's `CameraState`property and `AbortExposure()` procedure inside of `Execute()`, or override `DoTerminate()`, as well.

The `TThread.Terminate()` method simply sets the `TThread.Terminated` property to true, it does nothing else.  It is the responsibility of `Execute()` to check the `Terminated` property periodically and exit as soon as possible.  Your `while` that waits for the camera's `ImageReady` property to be true can, and should, check the thread's `Terminated` property so it can stop waiting when requested.

Try something more like this:

```
class TThreadCamera : public TThread
{
private:
  bool init;

protected:
  void __fastcall Execute();
  void __fastcall DoTerminate();

public:
  __fastcall TThreadCamera();
};
```

```
__fastcall TThreadCamera::TThreadCamera()
  : TThread(false)
{
  FreeOnTerminate = true;
}

void __fastcall TThreadCamera::Execute()
{
  init = SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL));
  if (!init) return;
  Variant Camera = Variant::CreateObject("ASCOM.Simulator.Camera");
  Camera.OlePropertySet("Connected", true);
  Camera.OleProcedure("StartExposure", 60, true);
  while (!Terminated)
  {
    if ((bool) Camera.OlePropertyGet("ImageReady"))
      return;
    Sleep(100);
  }
  if (Camera.OlePropertyGet("CameraState") == 2) // Exposure currently in progress
    Camera.OleProcedure("AbortExposure");
}

void __fastcall TThreadCamera::DoTerminate()
{
  if (init) CoUninitialize();
  TThread::DoTerminated();
}
```

Or:

```
class TThreadCamera : public TThread
{
protected:
  void __fastcall Execute();

public:
  __fastcall TThreadCamera();
};
```

```
#include <utilcls.h>

__fastcall TThreadCamera::TThreadCamera()
  : TThread(false)
{
  FreeOnTerminate = true;
}

void __fastcall TThreadCamera::Execute()
{
  TInitOle oleInit;
  Variant Camera = Variant::CreateObject("ASCOM.Simulator.Camera");
  Camera.OlePropertySet("Connected", true);
  Camera.OleProcedure("StartExposure", 60, true);
  while (!Terminated)
  {
    if ((bool) Camera.OlePropertyGet("ImageReady"))
      return;
    Sleep(100);
  }
  if (Camera.OlePropertyGet("CameraState") == 2) // Exposure currently in progress
    Camera.OleProcedure("AbortExposure");
}
```

Comment: `CoUninitialize` is clearly better in matching try finally, or RAII, for clarity and avoiding dealing with case where Execute does not run. Shelving it off to `DoTerminate` is a really opaque and obfuscated way to deal with this.

Comment: @user You commented to my answer that what is said here was no good to you. What changed?

Comment: Your explanation was overall very useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: @user1125432 You should accept one of these answers though. Since all three say essentially the same thing, pick the one you found most useful.